# app crash when success initialize data MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mvvm

my apps crash when I try to passing the data into another controller but it was successfully load data in my viewController. it's kinda weird though because the data successfully display in my label and my imageView in my controller, what can I suspect is the data is not yet being load. but if the data not being load why the imageView display my data, here I show you my code.

```
// This is my schoolListViewModel
class SchoolListViewModel {

    private(set) var schoolListViewModel = [SchoolViewModel]()
    private let services: ProfileServices
    private let schools = UserDefaults.getSelectedSchool()

    var count: Int {
        return schoolListViewModel.count
    }

    var id: String {
        selectedSchoolID()
    }

    var imageUrl: String {
        selectedSchoolImageURL()
    }

    var schoolName: String {
        selectedSchoolName()
    }

    var schoolCity: String {
        selectedSchoolCity()
    }

    init(services: ProfileServices) {
        self.services = services
    }
}

extension SchoolListViewModel {

    func loadData(success: @escaping (() -> Void), failure: @escaping ((String) -> Void)) {
        services.fetchSchoolList { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let schools):
                self?.schoolListViewModel = schools.compactMap({ SchoolViewModel(school: $0)
                })
                success()
            case .failure(let error):
                failure(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

// this is in my profileViewController
   var schoolListViewModel: SchoolListViewModel!
   private let profileServices = ProfileServices()

// this is my viewModel in my viewDidLoad
   progressHUD.show(in: self.view)
   schoolListViewModel = SchoolListViewModel(services: profileServices)
   schoolListViewModel.loadData(success: {
      self.progressHUD.dismiss(animated: true)
      self.populateSchool()
   }) { [weak self] error in
      self?.showHUDWithError(error)
   }

   schoolSelectionBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePickSchool), for: .touchUpInside)

// This is my objc function
   private func showHUDWithError(_ error: String) {
        progressHUD.textLabel.text = "Error"
        progressHUD.detailTextLabel.text = error
        progressHUD.dismiss(afterDelay: 4)
    }

   @objc private func handlePickSchool() {
      let selectSchoolVC = SelectSchoolPopUpVC()
      selectSchoolVC.schoolListViewModel = schoolListViewModel

      present(selectSchoolVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

// this is in my SchoolPopUpVC controller
var schoolListViewModel: SchoolListViewModel!

// this is where the error goes in my schoolPopUpVC tableViewDataSource
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return schoolListViewModel.count
    }
```

this where when I try to passing the data, the error show in my tableView numberOfRowsInSection

> unexpected found nil when try to unwrapping optional value

Comment: Don't use `!` unless you want to crash - Unwrap your options properly and signal your view to refresh once the data load is complete - it is an asynchronous network operation.

Comment: but @Paulw11 I use a loading to wait the data complete, that's why it's wierd when the data complete but still crash. I update the question by the way, I add the progress loading after the asynchronous network is finish.

Comment: Which line does it crash on ?  Show that code.

Comment: @Paulw11 I update the question where the crash show up

Comment: Change it to `return schoolListViewModel?.count ?? 0` - avoid the force unwrap of a `nil`

Comment: hey it work @Paulw11 thank you!!. but why when the data is exist it still crash? that's why I confident using force unwrapping.

Comment: Because the table view accesses its row count before `viewDidLoad` the view is already loaded *did*Load . You could move your code to `viewWillLoad` but it is better to avoid the force unwrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an implicitly unwrapped optional for `schoolListViewModel` but you don't assign a value until `viewDidLoad` executes. As it's name implies, that method executes *after the view is loaded*.  You refer to `schoolListViewModel` in `numberOfRowsInSection` which will be called after the view is loaded but before `viewDidLoad` has executed, so you get a crash.

The simple fix is to conditionally unwrap `schoolListViewModel` in that method:

```
return schoolListViewModel?.count ?? 0
```